# Does the iPhone 3GS support iOS 5?

Tags: ios, iphone

Will the iPhone 3GS be compatible with iOS 5?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't belong here. Googling your exact query not only answers your question, but also shows how well the device can actually run the new OS. Again, I'm sorry to be rude, but this is just sheer laziness and could have been answered in "0.14 seconds" using Google.

Comment: [Jeff Atwood, is that you?](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

Comment: @cksum: Alright. If you believe it doesn't belong here, you can flag the post to be deleted or bring the subject up in meta.

Comment: How is this question localized? I understand it could be closed for "JFGI", but there are millions of 3GS users out there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Apple, yes, iOS 5 will support the iPhone 3GS.

Apple's [product webpage](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html) for iOS 5 claims that iOS 5 is compatible with:

- iPhone 3GS
- iPhone 4
- iPod touch 3rd generation
- iPod touch 4th generation
- iPad
- iPad2

Comment: You're welcome. If it works for you, you can click the green check mark to "accept" the answer.

Comment: in a minute, when it lets me check it ;-)

Comment: Also worth noting: Both generations of iPad are supported.